# lightning network bitcoin howto install

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network

Hello fellow bitcoiners,

I would like to install lightning over Bitcoin core - I already have a full node. But every guide I follow ends up with a broken build or some issue preventing to finish the install of lightning. Did you have success with a good howto by any chance? I would preciate if someone could post a proven working install howto.

Thank you very much, /cr!?ptal

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: linux ubuntu based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:lightningnetwork/ppa
sudo apt-get install bitcoind lightningd
```

If you don't want to add external repositories you can flollow the clightning docs from https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.md they worked perfectly last time I checked and are copied here for your convenience.

### Library Requirements

You will need several development libraries:

- libsqlite3: for database support.
- libgmp: for secp256k1
- zlib: for compression routines.

For actually doing development and running the tests, you will also need:

- pip3: to install python-bitcoinlib
- valgrind: for extra debugging checks

You will also need a version of bitcoind with segregated witness and `estimatesmartfee` economical node, such as the 0.16 or above.

### To Build on Ubuntu

OS version: Ubuntu 15.10 or above

Get dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y \
  autoconf automake build-essential git libtool libgmp-dev \
  libsqlite3-dev python python3 python3-mako net-tools zlib1g-dev libsodium-dev \
  git gettext
```

Clone lightning:

```
git clone https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git
cd lightning
```

For development or running tests, get additional dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -y valgrind python3-pip libpq-dev
sudo pip3 install -r tests/requirements.txt -r doc/requirements.txt
```

Build lightning:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Running lightning:

```
bitcoind --datadir=<path_to_blockchain> && ./lightningd/lightningd && ./cli/lightning-cli help
```

**Note**: You may need to include `testnet=1` in `bitcoin.conf`

Comment: thak you @Rene Pickhardt. I have an issue early on: $ sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
Usage: add-apt-repository [options] repository

add-apt-repository: error: no such option: -u

Comment: I removed "-u" option. Now I have another issue: sudo apt-get install bitcoind lightningd > "unable to locate package lightningd".

Comment: What happens if u do without adding external repositories to the package manager and step by step?

Comment: it just works :-) with a few corrections, I edit your response if I may

Comment: Sure! That is what the site is about. We work collaboratively to bring the best information / education together